# Can I Achieve This only with Css?

Tags: css

I did a little thing that I want to use for a website which will show about each of the team.
There are 3 social icons, which I positioned absolutely.
The layout is ok.
My problem is that I want to add it some css effect, but am not sure if css can do it.

Here is the plan.
1. I want when a user hovers over any of the social icon, it will slide up a bit. I know if the icons are positioned relative, I will just add transition to it and make it's hover- top:-5px; 
But since it's positioned absolute, it's not working. Is there a work around to this?

1. I want a situation when a user hovers over any of the icon, the big circle background carrying the human picture will change to the background color of that particular icon that was hovered.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/alex13/pen/AynDL) and the [fullscreen](http://codepen.io/alex13/full/AynDL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do this, as you are using the bottom position, transition on that instead.

```
.fb {
    background:#3b5998;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    left:110px;
    bottom:3px;
    transition: bottom 1s;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 1s;
}

.fb:hover{
    bottom:7px;
}
```

As for changing the background colour of the main image on hover of one of the icons, I'm not sure you're going to be able to achieve that with CSS alone, certainly not with your current markup.

Comment: thank u @David. This solved the number 1 issue. Then how do we walk around the number two issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `margin-bottom` on `.icon:hover`. That will add up to the `bottom` when positioning the icon.
2. I don't know if you can do it with your current markup. I had to restructure it slightly:

   - Moved `.pix` *after* `.icons` in the markup.
   - Moved the `.icon` class to the `<a>` links, so `.pix` is a *sibling* of each `.icon`.

   That way, you can use the sibling selector `.icon:hover ~ .pix` to target the picture when an icon is hovered, or further specify it to `.fb:hover ~ .pix` to target the picture when the Facebook icon is hovered. Then, it's just a matter of changing the `background` and optionally adding a nice transition so the colors fade smoothly.

Here, [have a forked pen](http://codepen.io/MattiasBuelens/pen/DFolu)!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bottom margin on hover then transition that.

```
.icon{
    border-radius:100%;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-bottom .5s;
            transition: margin-bottom .5s;
}
.icon:hover {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```